# XmlException: Root element is missing. Stream and XmlSerializer

Tags: c#

I am trying to run this app (code from net)but getting error XmlException: Root element is missing. Where am I doing wrong? (I am learning to work with XML requests).

Method:

```
 public static T postXMLData<T>(string xml)
        {    
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Requests.url);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new 
                StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseStr);

                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 
                var t = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(responseStream);  //error here
                return t;
               
            }
           
            throw new Exception("что то не так");
        }
```

When I run app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            var req = postXMLData<Responses.Response>(Requests.checkRequest());

            if (req.result==0)
            Console.WriteLine("ok");

            Console.ReadKey();
     }
```

Requests class:

```
 public static string checkPaymentRequisites(string payId, string service, string account, string amount)
        {
            string req = authReq + $"<providers> <checkPaymentRequisites> <payment id=\"{payId}\"> <from currency=\"{currency}\" amount=\"{amount}\"/> <to currency=\"{currency}\" service=\"{service}\" amount=\"{amount}\" account=\"{account}\" moneyType=\"{moneyType}\"/> <receipt id=\"{receiptId}\" date=\"{dTime}\"/> </payment> </checkPaymentRequisites> </providers> </request>";
            return req;
```

Responses class:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "payment")]
        public class Payment
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "date")]
            public DateTime date { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fatal")]
            public string fatal { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
            public string id { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "result")]
            public int result { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "saved")]
            public bool saved { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "status")]
            public int status { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "uid")]
            public long uid { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "checkPaymentRequisites")]
        public class checkPaymentRequisites
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName ="payment")]
            public Payment Payment { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName ="extras")]
            public Extras Extras { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName ="result")]
            public int result { get; set; }

        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "providers")]
        public class Providers
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "checkPaymentRequisites")]
            public checkPaymentRequisites checkPaymentRequisites { get; set; }

        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName ="response")]
        public class Response
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName ="providers")]
            public Providers Providers { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName ="result")]
            public int result { get; set; }

            //[XmlText]
            //public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```

The main goal of the app is to deserialize and to display Response from Request in XML.

Comment: If we can't see the XML, we can't say for sure what's wrong, but the error message is pretty clear and plainly worded - what part of **Root element is missing** isn't clear?

Comment: Actually I want to display XML response(in XML format) and to Deserializ also. To display to see the response I get from request and Deserialize to work with XMLElements.

Comment: You pass Requests.checkRequest()) as a xml string, but if it is not, then it is going to get an error like this.

Comment: here the Response <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response result="0">
 <providers>
  <addOfflinePayment result="0">
   <payment date="text" fatal="false" id="text" result="0" saved="true" status="1"
    uid="text">
    
   </payment>
  </addOfflinePayment>
 </providers>
</response>

Comment: What is Requests.url? What namespace is Responses in?

Comment: `string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();` What is this doing here? It's going to read the whole thing and leave the serializer with nothing to read. Just remove it. Alternatively call `xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(responseStr))`

Comment: @Charlieface I would like to deserialize and to display xml, thats the main I want. Thats why I thought ReadToEnd() will help to display but  unfortunately its error. How to do both deserialize and display in same method?

Comment: @user103 Requests is class where I wrote Xml requests to send and REsponse is class too where I wrote XmlElements

Comment: Can you also post these two classes?

Comment: @user103 I posted those two classess

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to read the response twice. The stream can only be read once.

So either you can just deserialize it

```cs
using var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 
var t = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(responseStream);
```

Or you can first copy it into a string to dump to console, then deserialize from that string.

```cs
using var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream)
string responseStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseStr);
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 
var t = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(responseStr));
```

---

However you have a number of other serious issues in your code:

- Use of `WebRequest` which is deprecated and really old. Use `HttpClient` instead.
- You should use `await` to better manage responsiveness
- You are not disposing the stream, nor many other `IDisposable` objects.
- You should cache the `XmlSerializer`
- You have a mismatch between the encoding you are using and the encod

```cs
private static HttpClient _client = new();  // cache the client and serializer
private static XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer = new(typeof(T)); 

public static async Task<T> postXMLData<T>(string xml)
{    
    Console.WriteLine(xml);

    using var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Requests.url);
    message.Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'");

    using var response = await _client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseStr);

    var t = (T)_xmlSerializer.Deserialize(responseStream);
    return t;
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var req = await postXMLData<Responses.Response>(Requests.checkRequest());

    if (req.result == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("ok");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If you want to read it as a stream then use

```cs
    using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    var responseStr = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Comment: Charlieface Code you wrote below "Or you can first copy it into a string to dump to console, then deserialize from that string" missing root in 5th line. Same code I tried before.

Comment: and `StringReader` cant convert `responseStream` to System.IO.Stream

Comment: Sorry should be `responseStr` see edit

Comment: Charlieface  good, but response I got by error of  "request data error". Meanwhile from Postman its ok.

Comment: *I got by error of "request data error"* what does that mean? Did you get an exception? What was the message? Or did you get an unusual response?

Comment: Charlieface I got unusual response, like when I enter something wrong in parameters I get same response, but all parameters are ok when I try with postman

Comment: There may be differences in the headers. Use a tool such as Fiddler to capture the requests and compare